# How do I Redirect a URL in PHP using .htaccess? 

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect a URL in PHP? If I use `.htaccess` to redirect, then it's asking me for authentication (username & password). I want to redirect to a URL without any authentication.
Is it possible in PHP? 
I don't want to use headers or meta tags or `window.location` to redirect. Is there
any other way is possible?

Comment: This is not making much sense yet. Can you describe in detail what exactly you want to do? And what kind of authentication comes in at what point?

Comment: PHP and Htaccess are different. It is not possible to answer this question as it stands. Pick either PHP and use `header()` or htaccess and `Redirect example.com example.com/page [R=301]`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you perhaps copy/pasted some code into your .htaccess file has basic authentication?

You only need one line to do that in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /oldpath http://sitecom/newpath
```